# How to get custom music on Android in Unity2D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio-player

I have a game. In the game, you need the player to upload their music to a folder with the name: "Game Name + music".

I found many solutions, but they all do not work on Android, only on PC

Comment: I think you need to create a native Android plugin that will handle your filesystem access and call it from Unity.